# jquery dynamic <h> tags not recognize in SEO checker sites

Tags: jquery, html, seo

I have a problem, when I add  inline  tags in html webpages , SEO checker sites recognize them but when I  add   tags from Jquery code, they don't recognize them, why don't SEO checker sites recognize dynamic  tags ?
Thanks.

Comment: All the content served from server that only can be SEOed.

Comment: I have a dynamic list and I should retrieve items with ajax and webservice in  "load more" button. Isn't  a way???

Comment: dynamic contents are hard to implement for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Most SEO checkers do not execute javascript code fetched from the server. So If you add a content dynamically it is not visible for SEO chekers and what is more importantly this content is not visible for search engines also.

Though Google has a crawler that *can* execute javascript it doesn't execute it for all pages as it is quite expensive in terms of computation resources. Only fpr popular pages that have significant traffic and PR the javascript code is executed.

So when SEO checkers ignore javascript they have strong reasons doing so.

If you want more details read this: https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/122/does-google-execute-javascript and this http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

Comment: Thanks mylh for your answer.